# Mongo Shell convert string to nuuid and compare

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I would like to do the following:

```
    db
    .getCollection('COLLECTION')
    .find({ $where : function() { return NUUID(this.Col1) != this.Col2 }})
```

Where Col1 contains NUUID strings and Col2 contains NUUIDs.

I would like rows where the NUUID value of Col1 (which is a string) is not equal to Col2.

I receive the error: `ReferenceError: NUUID is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/uuidhelpers.js , the solution is:

```
db
.getCollection('TestColl')
.find({$where: function(){

    function CSUUID(uuid) {
        var hex = uuid.replace(/[{}-]/g, ""); // remove extra characters
        var a = hex.substr(6, 2) + hex.substr(4, 2) + hex.substr(2, 2) + hex.substr(0, 2);
        var b = hex.substr(10, 2) + hex.substr(8, 2);
        var c = hex.substr(14, 2) + hex.substr(12, 2);
        var d = hex.substr(16, 16);
        hex = a + b + c + d;
        var base64 = HexToBase64(hex);
        return new BinData(3, base64);
    }

    function HexToBase64(hex) {
        var base64Digits = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        var base64 = "";
        var group;
        for (var i = 0; i < 30; i += 6) {
            group = parseInt(hex.substr(i, 6), 16);
            base64 += base64Digits[(group >> 18) & 0x3f];
            base64 += base64Digits[(group >> 12) & 0x3f];
            base64 += base64Digits[(group >> 6) & 0x3f];
            base64 += base64Digits[group & 0x3f];
        }
        group = parseInt(hex.substr(30, 2), 16);
        base64 += base64Digits[(group >> 2) & 0x3f];
        base64 += base64Digits[(group << 4) & 0x3f];
        base64 += "==";
        return base64;
    }

    return CSUUID(this['Col1']).toString() != this['Col2'].toString()

    }
})
```